# Can I rasterize a population data (the population data is joint with district)

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I have tried rasterizing the population data, which is joint to the district vector file. A new file is generated but I cannot see anything. Was just wondering if it's the symbology problem or the rasterizing problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a spatial reference problem, creating data that is in the wrong location and far away, can you provide spatial reference info on the layer you're rasterizing and the canvas. It could also be a symbology problem as you say, what sort of raster layer symbology are you using?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have tried to click the zoom to layer button and it shows its still on my study area. While for the symbology, i was using the single band pseudocolour, please see attached.

Comment: You've created a raster that is 5 pixels wide and 5 pixels high, change your *Output Raster Size Units* to metres (meters), I expect that is what you really want. Your data has a coordinate reference system of EPSG:2326 (Hong Kong 1980 Grid System) units:metre so 5m cells sounds appropriate. What is the CRS of the canvas? If there is no known direct transformation the raster will not intersect. Also your geometries might be bad, this is known to cause unpredictable results, have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203685/resolving-geometry-errors-in-qgis and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thank you for our reply! however. there is only pixel and georeferenced units for me to choose.

Comment: `georeferenced units` is meters (depending on the CRS you use).

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have changed to georeferenced units but there is still nothing to be seen after the layer is created...